# Adobe Pro: Changing Color of FreeText Annotations with Javascript

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm using Adobe Pro to edit PDFs in which a lot of Additions have been entered in the Form of FreeText Annotations.
Now i want to write a Script to Change the Textcolor in these to Black. It already works for Lines/Circles/... but not for the actual Text.

Here is what i have so far:

```
/* Bla */
var myDoc = event.target.doc;

if(!myDoc)
    console.println("Failed to access document");
else
    console.println("Opened Document");

//Color all Comments in Black
function colorComments(myDoc)
    {
    //Get a list of Comments
    var commentList = myDoc.getAnnots();
        if(commentList == null)
        {
            console.println("Failed to get Comments");
        }
        else
        {
            console.println("Found " + commentList.length + " Comments, Iterating through comments");
        }

    //Iterate through the comment List and change the Colors
    for each(comment in commentList)
    {
        if(comment == null)
        {
            console.println("Found undefined annot!");
        }

        switch(comment.type)
        {
            case "FreeText":
            {
                //change stroke color
                comment.strokeColor = color.black;
                var contents = comment.richContents;
                //Go through all spans and change the text color in each one
                for each(s in contents)
                {
                    console.println(s.text);
                    s.textColor = color.black;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

colorComments(myDoc);
```

Which prints the Contents of the Text in the Console, but the Color doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the "Span" object gets copied instead of referenced somewhere in my code.
Creating a array to hold the changed Spans and then assigning the array to comment.richContents seems to work fine.

```
case "FreeText":
{
  var spans = new Array;
  for each(span in comment.richContents)
  {
    span.textColor = color.red;
    spans[spans.length] = span;
  }
  comment.richContents = spans;
  break;
}
```

That works fine. (iterating over `comments.richContents` directly and changing the `for each` loop to a `for` loop didn't change the result though.

The answer to WHY it didn't work probably lies somewhere in the specifics of JS.